# How does Option act like a collection, when it isn't one?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

The accepted answer to "[How to convert a Some(“ ”) to None in one-line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9569076/how-to-convert-a-some-to-none-in-one-line)" took the form:

```
def convert(x: Option[String]) : Option[String] = 
    x.map(_.trim()).filterNot(_.isEmpty())
```

My problem is that I can't figure out how to find by what means the collection returned by filterNot is converted to an Option.  I looked at the Scaladoc for Option constructors, Option Object, Predef, Seq, and Seq Object.  I figure there's probably an implicit somewhere, but how does one go about finding it?

Comment: It doesn't act like a collection, it acts like a monad. As do collections.

Comment: @LuigiPlinge: Something with foreach and iterator is a collection, at least by _my_ duck test - these methods are not intrinsic to monads, are they?  In what way are you saying that it does not act as a collection - or aren't you?

Comment: In this example you're saying it's like a collection because it has `map` and `filter` methods. But these are monad operations (along with `flatMap`). Sure, you can think of Options as like collections (there's even an implicit conversion to `List`) but it's irrelevant for this question. It's like saying `Option` is like a `Foo` because they both have a `toString` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In scaladoc, you can click the "by inheritance" ordering button (it appears just above the methods description). This should help you finding the concrete implementation of a given method. The jump to that class and have a look to the source (the links to the source appears in the class/trait/object description).

In the case of Options, there are methods called `map`, `filter`, etc.

When an implicit value is required, you will notice, either an `implicit` clause in the argument list, or a context bound like `[A: MyImplicit]` in the parameters. Implicit are usually imported or declared in the companion object.

If you have a more specification question/example, please let me know.

Comment: Ah! Sorry, I finally got it.  I had assumed that Option would have some indicating trait or inheritance if it were itself a collection - once I saw that it was just a Product, I didn't even look at its own members, because I "knew" that `map`, et al wouldn't be there.

Comment: The concrete implementations of a given method are always given below its description.

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral Do you mean the definition class ?

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral: They're only there if you actually bother to look at them ;-( - which I didn't (see earlier comment).

Comment: @paradigmatic Below the description of a method there's a list of classes/traits. The last one is the definition class/trait, and all the others are overrides, in the order of precedence (ie, the first class/trait contains the implementation that will actually be called).